# What is the general procedure to appeal a rejected edit to documentation?

Tags: support, edits, documentation

In the purely hypothetical scenario that I suggest an edit to a documentation post and it is rejected on the basis of, say, containing factually inaccurate information, how can one appeal the rejection if they believe the information is correct?

Comment: If anything, ___don't___ just suggest the same edit again. The best course of action at this moment would probably to discuss the rejection with the other user, in chat.

Comment: I've seen this go both ways enough I've just given up on documentation for the time being until more of the details are sorted out. Too many edits that add wrong information and I've seen correct edits rejected because the reviewer wasn't actually knowledgeable enough to be doing proper review.

Comment: If there is any feedback just try to adhere to whatever was said and if the feedback was nonsense like it often is then the general procedure would be to edit it the best you can, try resubmitting it and seeing if it pleases the topic overlords and trigger happy down voters. Id recommend trying to pick topics that arent as populated with users if you can, it leads to less frustration and benefits the communities that are lacking in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there is no real way to appeal via the documentation UI. Meta or chat or GTFO, basically.

The only choice is resubmitting with the edit comment asking for why. But that's a really suboptimal solution.

And for me the issue is not only hypothetical. I have had a few users come into the general chat about documentation asking why I rejected their edit. There though are certainly many more users who do not use chat or where the reviewer is not in chat.

Thus, there's a real need for it, and hence I created an appropriate feature request:

[Commenting after approval and pinging reviewers of a Documentation change proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329880/2153758)